# Association direction in use case diagrams

Tags: uml

What is the meaning of the direction of an **association between actor and use case** in a UML **use case diagram**? Is it **data flow direction** or **control flow direction**? Does the standard say anything about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah no. This is an association, in the norm, association between actor and use has no direction. Please see image extracted from the norm.

The usage is: if the actor is on the left, it means that's a "primary actor", the actor who activates the use case. If the actor is on the right, it means that the actor is a secondary one: he participates to use case but does not activate it.

Please, take care to the multiplicity: "The example shows that a Customer or Administrator may or may not participate in any of their associated UseCases
(hence the 0..1 multiplicity). From the UseCase perspective, every UseCase in the example must have an Actor to
initiate it (hence the 1 multiplicity). The Deposit and Register ATM UseCases require participation by the Bank, while
the bank can participate with many Deposit and Register ATM UseCases at the same time." (extract, p641)

The point is if you get a lot of actors, keeping them on the left or the right is not easy. So "I" (but this is my way, not the norm) use directed association, if this is from the actor to the use case, it means that's the actor is a primary one, if this is from the use case to the actor it means this is a secondary one.

[image]

Comment: You forgot the picture. Rather than norm you should say UML specs. Left and right should be adorned with "of the boundary for the system under consideration".  And finally: this is just a widely used convention.

Comment: OMG is not a normative organization, but just a loose organization that's supported by a number of companies. In contrast ISO is a government organization and creates norms. "System under consideration" (SUC) is a common term. You would not need to stereotype the boundary in a UC diagram as it will represent the SUC implicitly. In/out and left/right are also (accepted) conventions, and not specified in UML. (hehe, now my answer is in front of your comment)

Comment: The image is coming :) For you a norm is different from spec since UML is not writen by a normalization organisation ? Why not. And for the system, this is strange but there is no meta-class System, there is one Model on which a stereotype SystemModel may be applied but i do not think that there is a meta-class System or SystemBoundary. So i try to avoid to speak about system when i model use cas. By definition, use cases are inside the system and actors outside.

Comment: Ah, and as we are at it: use correct UC names with predicate-subject(-object) in the diagram. And the multiplicities do not make any sense. Oh nooo. They are from the UML specs. They should be killed for that >:-(

Comment: No just correct some typos errors :) About "SUC",  a meta-class SystemBoundary would be useful since most of UML users draw a rectangle to show the system boundaries when they model uses cases. About norm or spec, you're even if i am not sure this is so meaningfull here.

Comment: For the multiplicity, i never use them with UC but this is in the specification ...  (copy/paste)

Comment: I would never cite UC related modeling from the UML specs. They are absolute nerds and have no idea of business modeling. Lots of the UC stuff in the specs is just toast.

Comment: We use them to define specifications with some customers, it is a way to analyze customer' needs. It is not so bad.

Comment: @ThomasKilian UML is [ISO/IEC 19505-1 and -2 international standard](https://www.iso.org/standard/32624.html).  It was released by ISO  together with [5 other OMG standards](http://www.omg.org/news/releases/pr2012/05-31-12.htm), like for example OCL.  So this specification is definitively a norm.  By the way,  here everything about the versions released to ISO: http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/About-UML/

Comment: @Christophe One never stops learning. So let's call it ISO 19505-1 and -2 instead of UML from now on.

Comment: Ah cool. And it's only 198 CHF. Why didn't I know that I also can buy it so cheapo?

Comment: @ThomasKilian well, don't worry, you can get it in your local currency from your national standard organisation as well... and fortunately, the OMG continues to provide it for free ;-)

Comment: if you look at OMG site, the iso adopted specification is not the last one no ?

Comment: Well, just to clarify both answers, both methods of presenting primary and secondary actors are not mentioned in the specification, however both are commonly recognized semi-standards. Take into consideration that sometimes the same actor can be at the same time primary to one UC and secondary to another in which case using sides to distinguish so would fail and you have to either use directed associations or use other techniques to represent this information. Also in the official OMG certification exam the directed associations are used as if they were a standard.

Comment: @granier ISO is at 2.4.1, OMG at 2.5. I stay with the non-norm since it's free. I wonder if their documentation is better than that of OMG, but at this price? The worst: since ISO is already paid by taxes, they still charge us an extra for that paper. Ridiculous.

Answer (score 3):

Direction in UC diagrams have no agreed common meaning. I once used directed vs. un-directed arrows to distinguish between primary and secondary actors (and wrote that down in the modeling directives of the domain). I'm not the only one doing that. And only later I learned that (as @granier pointed out) it's also common to just put primary actors left and secondary actors right of the system boundary.

N.B. As commented @granier the UC stuff in the UML spec is too techie. Some of it is fishy like include/extend which is simply mistaken for functional decomposition. The picture @granier took from the specs even lacks good wording for UC names. I'd rather go and read Bittner/Spence who really know what they are talking of in business terms.